# sinon spy module export new class

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I using mocha and sinon for unit test in node.js. I have a problem with mocking google auth library. This is part of code what want testing:

```
const GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();
const oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
```

I'm trying testing "new GoogleAuth()" and OAuth2 but nothing work.
This is my mock:

```
let googleMock = sinon.stub().returns({
    Oauth2: sinon.spy()
});
....
it('should call new GoogleAuth', function ()
  {
       expect(googleMock).calledWithNew();
  });
```

Error: expected stub to have been called with new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved like this:

```
let OAuth2Mock = sinon.stub(); 
let googleMock = sinon.spy(function () 
{ return { OAuth2: OAuth2Mock } } );
```